# Excel Slicer not able to filter a chart because of inactive relationship in data model

Tags: excel, data-modeling, powerpivot

I have created a dashboard on Excel and used a Year slicer to dynamically change charts. But 1st chart in my dashboard is not changing as per the slicer. I have created a Date Table in Excel data modeling and mapped date column from date table to various date columns in other tables. But at a time one relationship will be active.

The problem is with slicing data in 1st Sheet, Scheme_Details. Can anyone check my sheets, data model and relationships and find out why slicer is not getting applied on 1st chart that uses data from Scheme_Details sheet?

[Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brndZSRwr3b4i_3S7QbyKQQuB3BuW-pO/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=104504370309436209867&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I tried using USERELATIONSHIP in measure that didn't work?
Tried checking datatypes, they are matching.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by creating 2 date fields in the date table. First date field is linked to Scheme table and 2nd date field is linked to all other date fields in other tables. Used DAX measures in Excel charts instead of using direct columns. With the help of USERELATIONSHIP function used inactive relationships. Then used CUBEVALUE function to use measures as KPIs.

[date model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP3dv.png)

[KPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYkuh.png)